# How to remove Armature bone from Binary fbx export?

Tags: modifiers, export, armature, bones

Exporting from any blender version with binary fbx support leads to addition of a redundant bone at root with same name as the armature.

How do I disable addition of that root bone for binary fbx export?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the *bone* being exported is infact Blender's armature *object* (since Blender has an armature object, which can have multiple root bones in the armature).

Seems like this is a known bug, see this report: https://developer.blender.org/T45368 for details.